# WinSCP terminal through Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, winscp

While running the query through WinSCP, I got the results without the column name on top of each column.
Is there a way to get the column names in the results file?

Answer (score 0):

Hive CLI is deprecated, and you should use beeline instead. It'll add column names.

```
beeline -n $(whoami) -u jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10000
```

But I suggest you just use a JDBC application from Windows, if available